# Emacs: How to insert 'λ' instead of 'lambda' in Scheme mode?

Tags: emacs, unicode

Long ago, I came across a text editor function that replaced the word 'lambda' with the character 'λ'. I would like to do this in emacs. My preferences:

- I would like to activate this function in certain modes only (activate it for Scheme-mode but turn it off for C-mode for example).
- At work I still use an older version of emacs, so the solution should work for emacs22 and emacs23.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create a mode hook, which replaces `lambda` with the Greek character.

```
   (defun sm-greek-lambda ()
       (font-lock-add-keywords nil `(("\\<lambda\\>"
           (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
           ,(make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 107))
           nil))))))
```

Then you add this hook to your mode:

```
   (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'sm-greek-lambda)
```

Comment: It would be better to rename `sm-lambda-mode-hook` by `sm-replace-lambda` or `sm-greek-lambda`. `XXX-mode-hook` is usually used to identify hooks ran by `run-hook` by the specified mode and thus to which you can use `add-hook`.

Comment: Is `make-char` just there to support 22?

Comment: @Daimrod: Can you please explain the difference between a `XXX-mode-hook` and this custom one defined in the answer? Or at least point me to a useful documentation?

Comment: @rahmu: `xxx-mode-hook` is usually the name of the hook ran - with `run-hooks` - by the mode `xxx`. i.e. `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` is ran when the function `emacs-mode` is called. In this case, no hook is ran but a function is added to a hook. Look at the [Elisp Manual (Hooks)](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks) for more information.

Comment: @rahmu: Just to add a small example, you can do `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'some-function)` but `(add-hook 'sm-lambda-mode-hook 'some-function)` will never work unless you've some piece of code that does `(run-hooks 'sm-lambda-mode-hook)`.

Comment: @Daimrod: Thank you for the clear explanation. I'm updating the answer to add the better name.